# $x \cdot F_n$ is a linear combination of $\{ F_{n−1}, F_n, F_{n+1} \}$ for every positive integer $n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-polynomials, gram-schmidt

Let $F_n$ denote the $n$th polynomial obtained through Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization applied to
the sequence $$\{ 1, x, x^2, x^3 , \cdots , x^n \}$$
with the inner product $$ \int_0^1 f(x) \cdot g(x) dx.$$
I am trying to show that $x \cdot F_n$ is a linear combination of $\{ F_{n−1}, F_n, F_{n+1} \}$ for every positive integer $n$.

I tried using mathematical induction by assuming that this statement holds true for all $n = k$ and wanted to show this holds true for $n = k +1$. But I am having a hard time using the inductive hypothesis.

Comment: Explicitly, it seems true that if $a_n = \frac{n}{2\sqrt{4n^2-1}}$, then $a_n F_{n-1} + \frac12 F_n + a_{n+1} F_{n+1} = x F_n$. But proving this is overkill.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The polynomial $F_n$ satisfies $\deg F_n=n$ and is orthogonal to all polynomials of degree strictly less than $n.$ Hence for $k\le n-2$ we get
$$\langle xF_n,F_k\rangle =\int\limits_0^1xF_n(x)F_k(x)\,dx=\int\limits_0^1F_n(x)[xF_k(x)]\,dx=\langle F_n,xF_k\rangle =0$$ i.e. $xF_n$ is orthogonal to every polynomial $F_k$ for $k\le n-2.$ Thus $xF_n$ is a linear combination of $F_{n-1},F_n$ and $F_{n+1}.$

Comment: I like the approach. Question though what about having the inner product be 0 tells us that $xF_n$ is  a linear combination of $F_{n−1}, F_n
 and F_{n+1}.$?

Comment: The inner product is given by $\langle f,g\rangle= \int\limits_0^1f(x)g(x)\,dx,$$ although the property is valid for any inner product on the space of polynomials.

Comment: I guess I was curious about the intuition for using n-2?

Comment: The only intuition is that $(n-2)+1=n-1,$ and any polynomial of degree less than or equal $n-1$ is orthogonal to $F_n.$ Hence $xF_k\perp F_n$ for $k\le n-2,$ as $\deg(xF_k)=k+1\le n-1.$